# Rescue from an error that may not be defined

Tags: ruby, error-handling

My Rails website (this problem is purely Ruby based though) uses the AWS-SES (Action mailer using AWS) gem in test/development environment, and I am catching possible errors from email deliveries like this

```
def try_delivering_email(options = {})
    begin
      yield
      return false
    rescue  EOFError,
            ...
            AWS::SES::ResponseError,
            ... => e
      log_exception(e, options)
      return e
    end
end
```

Now the problem is that this gem is only defined for specific environments, in other words `AWS` does not exist in development, and the error checking code will therefore throw an error (haha) for undefined constant.

I have tried substuting that line for `(AWS::SES::ResponseError if defined?(AWS)` but then the next error I get is

> class or module required for rescue clause

How can I get around this in the nicest way possible ?

Comment: Why you can't use AWS::SES in development?

Comment: Well actually I can, but I usually don't load gems I know I do not use (in development I always use `letter_opener_web`, I don't want to send email for real), so in my gemfile I only added the `aws-ses` gem under the test/prod group

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception list of a *rescue-clause* doesn't have to be a literal/static list:

```
excs = [EOFError]
defined?(AWS) && excs << AWS::SES::Response
# ...
rescue *excs => e
```

The splat operator `*` is used here to convert an array into a list.

Comment: Oh nice ! We don't get to use that splat operator very often but it sure comes handy here ! Ruby's magic :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't include a conditional in a `rescue` clause, but you can blind rescue and then get picky about how to deal with it using conventional Ruby code:

```
rescue EOFError => e
  log_exception(e)

  e
rescue => e
  if (defined?(AWS) and e.is_a?(AWS::SES::Response))
    # ...
  else
    raise e
  end
end
```

It's not the nicest way, but it does the job. You could always encapsulate a lot of that into some module that tests more neatly:

```
def loggable_exception?(e)
  case (e)
  when EOFError, AnotherError, EtcError
    true
  else
    if (defined?(AWS) and e.is_a?(AWS::SES::Response))
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can do this as that method name should be self-explanatory:

```
rescue => e
  if (loggable_exception?(e))
    log_exception(e)

    e
  else
    raise e
  end
end
```

You could make this a little neater if `log_exception` returned the exception it was given. Don't forget Ruby is "`return` by default" and it doesn't need to be explicit unless you're doing it early.